# Can 燃える be used with the context of being embarassed?

Tags: verbs, idioms

I was just wondering if 燃える could be used in a context where someone gets embarassed to the point where they "burn up." Would it be taken literally or could it be used as an idiom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard it used In that sense. In that case, you would say 顔{かお}から火{ひ}が出{で}そう (I feel like fire is going to come out of my face).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can. 燃える is often used as ''getting fired up'' for something. In a embarassing situation you're better of with just 恥ずかしい